# Paginacion en react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, paginacion

Como hago para dejar seleccionada el link de la pagina en la que me encuentro con los estilos

que yo quiera personalizarles , cual es la manera mas eficiente de lograrlo? el componente del nav

lo tengo de la siguiente forma, donde se encuentra un menu para el responsive, pero me interesa

solo del lado desktop

```
function Navegador() {
  let Mostrar = useRef(),
    Cerrar = useRef(),
    Oculto = useRef();

  const AbrirMenu = (e) => {
    Oculto.current.style.display = 'flex'
    document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'
    setTimeout(() => {
        Oculto.current.style.transform = 'translate(0%)'
    }, 100);
}
const CerrarMenu = (e) => {
    Oculto.current.style.transform = 'translate(100%)'
    document.body.style.overflow = 'visible'
    setTimeout(() => {
        Oculto.current.style.display = 'none'
    }, 600);
}

return ( 
    <>
    <div className="nav" >
        <div className="logo" >
            <img src={Logo} alt=""/>
            <h1>GRAFICA | FYC</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="navegacion">
            <Link className="link" to={'/'}>Inicio</Link>
            <Link className="link" to={'/Galeria'}>Galeria</Link>
            <Link className="link" to={'/Contacto'}>Contacto</Link>
            <Link className="link" to={'/Conocenos'}>Conocenos</Link>
        </div>
        <div className="oculto">
            <span onClick={AbrirMenu} ref={Mostrar} className="material-symbols-outlined bars">
                menu
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div ref={Oculto} className="menu-oculto">
        <Link className="link-rsp" onClick={CerrarMenu} to={'/'}>Inicio</Link>
        <Link className="link-rsp" onClick={CerrarMenu} to={'/Galeria'}>Galeria</Link>
        <Link className="link-rsp" onClick={CerrarMenu} to={'/Contacto'}>Contacto</Link>
        <Link className="link-rsp" onClick={CerrarMenu} to={'/Conocenos'}>Conocenos</Link>
        <span ref={Cerrar} onClick={CerrarMenu} className="close material-symbols-outlined">
            close
        </span>
    </div>
    </>
);
```

}

Comment: Con `window.location` obtienes los datos de la pagina, con `window.location.pathname` te dice en que página estás. Puedes comparar eso con cada ruta del link y si coincide añadirle una clase en la que les asígnes los estilos que quieras

Comment: si, eso lo considere, a lo que me referia es si necesito un useefect o con referencias es suficiente?